# Initialise Tesseract before or after namedWindow from OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract

I wonder whether it is a bug or I do not understand something.

**Sample 1:**

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api;
api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
    exit(1);
}
namedWindow( window_name, CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );
```

**Result:**

```
Works fine.
```

**Sample 2:**

```
namedWindow( window_name, CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api;
api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

**Result:**

```
!strcmp(locale, "C"):Error:Assert failed:in file baseapi.cpp, line 192
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Difference:**
The order of creating window and initialisation of tesseract.
**Edit:**

```
locale = std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, nullptr);
ASSERT_HOST(!strcmp(locale, "C"));
```

This assert fails. Does it mean opencv sets locale and tesseract cannot change it?

Comment: Perhaps the opencv and tesseract conflict somehow through side-effects. You can find it out by debugging what actually failed in that init and why it does not fail when order is different.

Comment: Looks like you are not the only one with that [issue](https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j/issues/105). It is also mentioned as known issue on [tesseract github page](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/4.0x-Common-Errors-and-Resolutions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue of tesseract. Looking at the [github issue](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1670) Tesseract team is currently working on resolving it. 
As a temporary solution you can wrap all tesseract calls with the following code

```
// set locale to "C" for tesseract
char *old_ctype = strdup(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL));
setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
// some tesseract function, this is just an example.
tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
api.InitForAnalysePage();

// restore your previous locale
setlocale(LC_ALL, old_ctype);
free(old_ctype);
```